# wxpython double paneled window to show information

Tags: wxpython

I want to create two panels on one window (see example draw). Upper panel consists of a scrolled list with items. And when I click an item, the bottom panel show detailed info about this item. What I need to do to create such window with static and dynamic panels? What wx objects?

Or maybe there is a simpler method to achieve my goal with wx?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just created two `wx.Panels`, but I do not know, hot to create above list with such feature: when you click an item, the new panel is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply by creating just one `wx.Panel` object and a `wx.BoxSizer` that has its orientation set to `wx.VERTICAL`.

Then add a `wx.ListCtrl` for the first top widget. The parent will be the panel, but you will add it to the sizer object. I actually prefer using `ObjectListView` over `wx.ListCtrl`, but it is a separate add-on widget for wxPython. The bottom widget could be a second `wx.ListCtrl` or perhaps a `wx.ListBox`

When you create the second widget, just call its `Hide()` method so it is not shown initially. Or you can create the second widget only when an item in the first widget is selected. If you create it and Hide the second widget, then you would use the item selection event to Show it.

Comment: nice idea! I will try. No experience with wx, so I ask so simple question.

Comment: Correct: `wx.ListCtrl` and binding a function that draw bottom simple `wx.Panel` panel when `EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED` event occurs.